# String from database gives nullPointerException using isEmpty

Tags: java, android, string, android-sqlite

I have method that returns string from my DB.
My problem is when im trying to use `isEmpty()` or `charAt(0)` i get nullPointerException.
here is the log cat:

```
05-09 15:56:47.002: E/AndroidRuntime(6914): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-09 15:56:47.002: E/AndroidRuntime(6914): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.app.Application: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-09 15:56:47.002: E/AndroidRuntime(6914):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:504)
05-09 15:56:47.002: E/AndroidRuntime(6914):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4364)
05-09 15:56:47.002: E/AndroidRuntime(6914):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-09 15:56:47.002: E/AndroidRuntime(6914):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
```

---

```
   public boolean setTheCorrectParameterFields(){

            String mine = "";

            String spinnerExercise = workOutChoose.getSelectedItem().toString();
            DataBaseMain fieldsNum = new DataBaseMain(getApplicationContext());
            fieldsNum.open();
            mine = fieldsNum.getParameters(spinnerExercise);
            fieldsNum.close();

            if(mine.isEmpty())
                return false;
            return true;
            }
```

Comment: IF that's the line its crashing at, then getParameters is returning null.  Can't help more because we don't have the code for that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mine` is `null` on return from `fieldsNum.getParameters(spinnerExercise)`. You need to check for a non-`null` value before trying to do other things with it.

Answer (score 0):

Because `isEmpty` is a method on a `null` object, you can not call it.  You should try this instead:

```
  boolean empty = mine == null || mine.isEmpty() ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a method which allows you to do a `null`-safe empty check on a `String` in Commons Lang 3.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: Oh why Commons? There is an equivalent in Android SDK, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence)